# Microsoft Reporting not accepting report parameter

Tags: c#, reporting-services

When calling `reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("name", "deviceInfo");`

I get the following exception

> ReportServerException occurred
>
> Additional information: This report
>   requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter
>   'MyParam'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a
>   parameter value. (rsReportParameterValueNotSet)

But the report parameters I'm settting clearly contain 'MyParam';

```
 reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParams);
```

If step through the code with the debugger `reportParams` is an IEnumerable of ReportParameter and one of the parameters has the name 'MyParam' with a string collection of (count 1) with a string value inside.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the value for the "MyParam" is a single value, also check and make sure the "MyParam" parameter is defined from your report template and take string value, you could also add a default value from the report template itself.

```
var reportParams = new List<ReportParameter>();

// make sure access the first item from the string collection
var myParam = new ReportParameter("MyParam", stringCollection[0]);
reportParams.Add(myParam );

reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParams);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter when passing in a single string or collecting of strings as the value as the `ReportParameter` will return a string collection anyway
`public StringCollection Values { get; }`. I'm guessing it could be configuration on the reporting side

Comment: But I am passing a single string to the constructor anyway